# Conflict between Lightbox to and Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, conflict, flexslider

Im fairly new to JavaScript so finding it hard to understand. But Im making a homepage and I want an image slide show and Lightbox together, and I guess there a conflict between the different Js libraries. I also have read things like the No.Conflict script on the jQuery website but I have no idea on how to implement on to my HTML. Heres the code.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>


<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If some one can help me out that would be amazing. and put it in the simplest form would be super as well, as like I said Im quite new.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think there is a conflict?

Comment: You're loading jquery twice (js/1.7.2 and from googleapis).

Comment: there is no conflict, you are loading 2 jquery library, this is not necessary, what is type of element `.flexslider`?

Comment: Okay, brilliant. I thought it would be conflicting because when I put one in, the other did not work. Which one should I remove?

Comment: Sorry Tim, Im not to sure what you mean by an element. Still very confusing at the moment, Im am learning slowly though. Thanks guys

Comment: what exactly is the problem that you're having? Like what @tzerb asked, what makes you think that there's a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

remove the first script library from google and add only the .js jQuery file with your site